# Asp.net Application State expiration

Tags: asp.net, web-applications, web-config

I suppose that application state and session state are two different things.

If I can set expiration time to session state, can I do same to an application state in my web.config ?

I just want to prevent my application from rebuilding after 5 minutes.

I don't know exactly what happens. When accessing the website for the first time, the site takes 10 seconds to appear. If I return to the site before 5 minutes, the site appears immediately. If there are more than 5 minutes of inactivity, when I access the site again, the site takes 10 seconds. I guess it was the application state Who expired ?

Comment: What do you mean that your application "rebuild after 5 minutes"? Please explain exactly what that means.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest way I know of to keep your site alive is to make sure traffic is always coming through. If you have access to a scheduled job runner, have it ping a dummy aspx page every minute or two - this way, your app should run indefinitely.

If not, there are techniques to cheat the system. You can have a cache item built, and upon expiration of that cache item, create another cache item. This will perpetually keep running code every X minutes, which will keep the app alive. The problem with this is that if the app ever does die (server reboot, IIS restart, etc.), the app will be dead until someone makes a real request, at which point it will stay alive indefinitely again.

This technique is sometimes used to simulate a task scheduler in ASP.NET. Just keep in mind that it's not perfect.

**EDIT**: For clarification, you wouldn't just create a new cache item, you'd actually make a request to a page which would then in turn create the cache item. This ensures that another request is made through IIS, which in turn runs the full lifecycle, keeping the app alive.

Even if you do set your session timeout high, there's no guarantee that it will hold. I've dealt with hosting companies who will recycle your application pool after just a couple minutes of inactivity, killing any sessions you may have open. They don't care that you may have sessions open - they are just trying to squeeze every CPU cycle they can out of their servers. So if you're on shared hosting, you may want to keep that in mind - you may not be able to control how often they kill your app.

Answer (score 0):

Application State starts when the first session is created, and is automatically ended after the last session expires.  As long as you have continued access to the website, the application will remain active.

I don't know what you mean by having application "rebuild".  Changing any file related (i.e. file with compilable code) will cause the application to either recompile (if you have a web directory) or reload (if you have a web application).  This action will always end all sessions and end the application.

Comment: Well, if you have your session timeout at 5 minutes, then 5 minutes after the last access, the session will expire and the application will unload.  on the first new access after that, the application has to be reloaded and that does take some time.  The default timeout for a session is 20 minutes and unless you have reason to change that, I would recommend leaving it alone.  Are you executing any code on the Application_Start event of the Global.asax.vb (or .cx)?  That executes every time the application starts up.  Also, which version of IIS are you using?

Comment: BTW, you can control the timeout in your web.config, in the system.web section using the sessionState tag: <sessionState timeout="20" />

Answer (score 0):

Not sure it is still actual.

The problem doesn't linked with SessionState or ApplicationState.

To avoid slow reaction of your web-site you have to activate **AlwaysRunning** mode of your IIS
To do that add to your web.config the next

```
<applicationPools> 
    <add name="MyAppWorkerProcess" startMode="AlwaysRunning" /> 
</applicationPools>
```

Answer (score -2):

You can configure your session state in your configuration file for preventing this expiration. 
For example:

```
<sessionState 
            mode="SQLServer"
            sqlConnectionString="data source=127.0.0.1;user id=<username>;password=<strongpassword>"
            cookieless="false" 
            timeout="20" 
    />
```

Comment: The question is asumming your answer and asking about Application State: "If I can set expiration time to session state, can I do same to an application state in my web.config ?"